# Angular multiple local reference in a list view for each item

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using `nativescript-angular` for my project. [Here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-zoom-and-drag/blob/master/app/item/items.component.html) there is an implementation for zooming. It uses local reference (#item) and `@ViewChild` decoration in order to accessing the element:

```
<GridLayout (pan)="onPan($event)" (pinch)="onPinch($event)" (doubleTap)="onDoubleTap($event)" class="page">
<StackLayout #item width="200" height="200" backgroundColor="Green">
    <Image src="res://icon" width="50" height="50" class="p-20"></Image>        
    <!-- all children ot the element #item will scale accordingly-->
</StackLayout>
<TextView #status row="1" editable="false"></TextView>
```

And in component:

```
@ViewChild("item") angularItem: ElementRef;
```

It works fine. But I want to use it in a **ListView**. My list view is something like this:

```
<ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <Label [text]="item.name" class="list-group-item"></Label>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

How can I define local references for each item that I could be able to zoom each element?

Comment: You can use reactive form model https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the object reference from the arguments passed to the event using `args.object`.

in your case something like this.

```
<ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <Label (pan)="onPan($event)" [text]="item.name" class="list-group-item"></Label>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

and you can get Label reference in onPan function by using `$event.object`

```
onPan(args){
  let label=<Label>args.object;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I use `args.object` instead of `@ViewChild` , it becomes very laggy.

Comment: I was missing `page.getViewById("item");` . Thanks.

Comment: And one more question.As there is no enough space in a ListView , I can not zoom the image as much as before. Any idea?

Comment: When I want to use `transformation` instead of `scaleX` , I get the following: `Property 'transformation' does not exist on type 'view'`. How should I do that?

Comment: It works in a simple image. But when I use it in a list view, there no much space too zoom. It only zooms a bit.